# Auto Save for R Console

Tags: r, console, autosave

When working within the R console on my windows 32-bit computer R has a tendency to freeze up during simulations, MLE procedures and any other computationally heavy routine.  I was wondering if anyone had any thoughts on an auto save script or a way to back up the file without having to constantly save the work.

Comment: how about using Rstudio? It tends to keep your modifications intact even if  R freezes and you didn't save.

Comment: That is what I use on my private computer but unfortunately for the work computer I can only get base R.

Comment: How about using the zip file of Rstudio? Then you don't install anything in the registry. Otherwise a text editor like notepad++ or something and source the script.

Comment: I've actually tried to download Rstudio from a zip file a couple of different times but I never could get it to work.  Any instructions you could provide from both would be a great deal of help

Comment: I never had any issues with it. My steps are always, download the zip file to my D-drive, unzip in a folder, create a short-cut to the Rtudio.exe file in the bin folder. And that's it. Always works for me. But your machine might be secured even more tightly than mine. Because you will get a popup "open file - security warning". Because the publisher can not be verified, since it the program comes from a zip file and not an exe or msi file